# Vacuuming Postgresql has used up disk space

Tags: postgresql

I have just run Vacuum on a Postgres table to try to recover disk space, however the result is that all the disk space has been consumed.  Does Vacuum crete log files or transaction logs that can be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you performed a `VACUUM FULL` as the standard `VACUUM` just makes space in the data file that is associated with deleted records free so that Postgres can use that space for new records.  It doesn't release the space to the operating system.

`VACUUM FULL` does release space, but it does this by copying all the information that it wants to keep from the data file into a new data file, and then when complete it deletes the old data file.   As such `VACUUM FULL` requires extra space while it is running.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html

Comment: yes, VACUUM FULL.  Once it has finished should it free disk space or are there logs to manually delete?  It is actually a small database, however the disk is full.